# OData7 Versioning Functions: AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched

Tags: c#, .net, odata, versioning

I cloned [a repository used to demonstrate versioning with OData 7](https://github.com/Fortelinea/ODataApiVersion) from Microsoft's dev blog and I have been unable to implement functions under different API versions.

Using the Customer controller, I added a function for each version 1 and 2 named 'CustomerRegistrationService' and defined them like so.

Controller Version 1:

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
    [ODataRoutePrefix("Customers")]
    public class CustomersController : ODataController
    {
        private Models.v1.Customer[] customers = new Models.v1.Customer[]
        {
            new Models.v1.Customer
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Sam",
                PhoneNumber = "111-222-3333"
            },
            new Models.v1.Customer
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Peter",
                PhoneNumber = "456-ABC-8888"
            }
        };

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Models.v1.Customer> Get()
        {
            return customers.AsQueryable<Models.v1.Customer>();
        }

        [HttpGet("{key}")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get(int key)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult CustomerRegistrationService(string ppsn = "", string dob = "", string doe = "")
        {

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Controller Version 2:

```
[ApiVersion("2")]
    [ODataRoutePrefix("Customers")]
    public class CustomersController : ODataController
    {
        private Models.v2.Customer[] customers = new Models.v2.Customer[]
        {
            new Models.v2.Customer
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Sam",
                PhoneNumber = "111-222-3333"
            },
            new Models.v2.Customer
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Peter",
                PhoneNumber = "456-ABC-8888"
            }
        };

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Models.v2.Customer> Get()
        {
            return customers.AsQueryable<Models.v2.Customer>();
        }

        [HttpGet("{key}")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get(int key)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult CustomerRegistrationService(string ppsn = "", string dob = "")
        {
            return Ok();
        }

    }
```

ODataModel Configuration

```
public class ODataModelConfiguration : IModelConfiguration
    {
        public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion, string? routePrefix)
        {
            switch (apiVersion.ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                    builder.EntitySet<Models.v1.Customer>("Customers")
                          .EntityType
                          .Select()
                          .Count()
                          .Filter()
                          .OrderBy();

                    var fnCustomerV1 = builder.EntityType<Models.v1.Customer>().Collection.Function("CustomerRegistrationService")
                        .ReturnsFromEntitySet<Models.v1.Customer>("Customers");
                    fnCustomerV1.Parameter<string>("ppsn").Optional();
                    fnCustomerV1.Parameter<string>("dob").Optional();
                    fnCustomerV1.Parameter<string>("doe").Optional();
                    fnCustomerV1.IsComposable = true;

                    break;

                case "2":
                    builder.EntitySet<Models.v2.Customer>("Customers")
                          .EntityType
                          .Count()
                          .Filter()
                          .OrderBy();

                    var fnCustomerV2 = builder.EntityType<Models.v2.Customer>().Collection.Function("CustomerRegistrationService")
                        .ReturnsFromEntitySet<Models.v2.Customer>("Customers");
                    fnCustomerV2.Parameter<string>("ppsn").Optional();
                    fnCustomerV2.Parameter<string>("dob").Optional();
                    fnCustomerV2.IsComposable = true;

                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Unsupported API version: {apiVersion}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The functions only have one difference in their ODataModel configuration: Version 1 accepts an additional parameter called 'doe'. When trying to call either Version of CustomerRegistrationService I receive the following status 500 error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

OData7Swagger.v1.Controllers.CustomersController.CustomerRegistrationService(string, string, string) (OData7Swagger)
OData7Swagger.v1.Controllers.CustomersController.CustomerRegistrationService(string, string, string) (OData7Swagger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DefaultApiVersionRoutePolicy.OnMultipleMatches(RouteContext context, ActionSelectionResult selectionResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.DefaultApiVersionRoutePolicy.Evaluate(RouteContext context, ActionSelectionResult selectionResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ODataApiVersionActionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(RouteContext context, IReadOnlyList`1 candidates)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.MvcRouteHandler.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Route.OnRouteMatched(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

From the cloned repository, I have only edited the files shown above, all startup.cs configuration is untouched and testing the controllers GET functionality which was given as an example, worked as expected.
Would anyone know what is causing this error, or if there is a rule against configuring same-named functions with different parameters?